# Android Studio Emulator is Running but not Showing/Working in my Mac

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

From avd manager, the run button says the emulator is running. but it's not visible and the app also not running/installing.

My device is MacBook with bigsur, I'm using the latest stable version of android studio, I'm also using adb wifi plugin but disabled this plugin too. but nothing happened.

I also deleted my avd and installed a new device but had the same issue.

Anyone facing this issue or have any solution then please share your comment...

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue in monterey 12.2, I posted my question in StackOverflow as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/70900743/4180091