# Updated to monetery 12.2 Mac OS, Android studio emulator not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-bumblebee

I have updated the Mac version of monetary 12.2. From there onwards, the studio emulator is not working. I tried all ARM, X86, and X86-64 system images as well. Android studio shows me connecting to the emulator and can't see the emulator getting opened.

I am using android studio's latest version Bumblebee V 2021.1.1.

Please find the image attached below.

[image]

Comment: You should try Genymotion Free, works better for me (create an account and chose Personal license): https://www.genymotion.com/download/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.

Quick fix, Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Tools -> Emulator

Now uncheck "Launch in a tool window"

Restart Android Studio.

Try starting the emulator now.

I think it's a bug.