# Android AVD image not starting after macOS update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have an android AVD image that used to work correctly. I had to update my macOS Big Sierra and after the update the AVD image is not starting. The error I get: the emulator process for avd was killed.

I tried the cold boot now option also I got same error.

Is there a way to run this AVD image without loosing the data that I have on it?

Comment: Same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900743/updated-to-monetery-12-2-mac-os-android-studio-emulator-not-working#comment125341254_70900743

Comment: @cmak and no answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me: [Android emulators are not working on macOS Big Sur 11.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576252/android-emulators-are-not-working-on-macos-big-sur-11-3)

Disable then enable emulator in SDK tools.
Then add entitlements file and run commands.